# i want to auto create pages with shortcode when plugin is activated and delete when deactivated

Tags: plugin-development

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'new_page');

function new_page(){
    
    $page_title= 'home';
    
    if(get_page_by_title($page_title)== NULL){
        
    $home_page= array(
        'post_title'     => $page_title,
        'post_content'  => [gd_shortcode],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'page'
    );
     $the_page_id = wp_insert_post($home_page);
    }
    
}


function get_shortcode(){
    
        $shortcode ='the content to be added automatically when page is created';
            return $shortcode;
    }

add_shortcode('gd_shortcode','get_shortcode');

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_remove') ;

    function plugin_remove() {
    
     $the_page_title = get_option( "my_plugin_page_title" );
     $the_page_id = get_option( 'my_plugin_page_id' );
     
     if( $the_page_id ) {

            wp_delete_post( $the_page_id );
        }
    
    delete_option("my_plugin_page_title");
    delete_option("my_plugin_page_id");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a basic PHP problem rather than a WordPress problem.

`wp_insert_post` is expecting `'post_content'` but you've given it `'$post_content'` and it needs a string as it's value aka `"[gd_shortcode]"` not `[gd_shortcode]`.

The same is true of your post status, it has a `$` in it that should not be there.

See the examples at the official dev docs at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ for proper usage of `wp_insert_post`

Comment: i was written by mistake i have just edited it

Comment: Your questions code still has at least 1 of these issues, your shortcode is not inside quotes/a string